# clone a branch from GIT

Tags: git, openstack

I want to check out OpenStack Neutron's branch JUNO from the git repository. What is the right URI to do this? If I do

```
% git clone git://github.com/openstack/neutron/tree/stable/juno/
```

it says:

```
openstack/neutron/tree/stable/juno is not a valid repository name
```

However I do see this branch at https://github.com/openstack/neutron/tree/stable/juno/.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't clone a branch, you clone an entire project:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/openstack/neutron
Cloning into 'neutron'...
remote: Counting objects: 105856, done.
remote: Total 105856 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (105856/105856), 44.17 MiB | 1.06 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (68444/68444), done.
```

After doing that, you can simply check out the branch you're interested in. E.g.:

```
$ git checkout -b juno -t origin/stable/juno
Branch juno set up to track remote branch stable/juno from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'juno'
```

Comment: Not entirely true; you can fetch the history for only a single branch with `git clone --singlebranch --branch stable/juno git://github.com/openstack/neutron`. That said, the single branch still had 94,000 objects and 60,000 deltas to download, so there's probably little reason not to grab the entire project.